# JupyterLab kernel log to web console

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-console, jupyter-kernel

I have created a jupyterlab extension and trying to execute a code in the kernel using requestExecute method. Registering the IOPub callback gives back the kernel output which i wanted it log to the JupyterLab web console extension.

execute code from kernel

```
let future = kernel.requestExecute({ code: 'a = 1' });

    future.onIOPub = msg => {
      console.log(msg.content); // how to print it to Jupyter Lab console ?
    };
```